# What is the proper way to load a fragment from within the Options Menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have the need for an options menu, which will be the same on all my fragments.  This code works for selecting and loading a fragment from the options menu.  However as we all know just because something works doesn't mean it's the proper way of doing it.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                            fragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;

                    }
```

Any and all feedback would be greatly appreciative.  Also as a side question at what point do you use a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reload data in those fragment everytime you load it then this is the correct way.

But if you need to set data only at one time then you need to transact fragment with tag and while loading fragment check for that tag to check if it is already exists in container view or not.

replace fragment like this:

```
MyFragment fragment  = new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.place_holder,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

wrap above code for in this `if` bracket.

```
fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
if(fragment == null){
    // ok, fragment is not already exists, so load it once.
} else {
   // Pop fragments to this tag

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (int i = 0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1; i--) {
        if (!fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newFragTag)){
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

so final code looks like,

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragment = (MyFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
if(fragment == null){
    // ok, fragment is not already exists, so load it once.

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.place_holder,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
} else {
   // Pop fragments to this tag
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1; i--) {
        if (!fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("myFragmentTag")){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right . it's just nothing much to it. for the activity try to separate them by your design pattern . like if you using `MVP` you can separate the activities based on the Entity. but still it's more based on type of project you are creating. also there is nothing wrong  with having many activities as long as you manage them to avoid memory leak and using low resources as much as possible.